Issue with laminas-test unit testing
I'm new to Laminas framework and Unit testing and working with a Laminas framework project and I want to start unit testing in that application. I used laminas-test package and followed their tutorial.
when I execute the vendor/bin/phpunit I'm getting the following error.
1) CompanyTest\Controller\ManageControllerTest::testDirectoryAction
Laminas\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: Service with name "ModuleManager" could not be created. Reason: Parameter to Laminas\ModuleManager\ModuleManager's Laminas\ModuleManager\ModuleManager::setModules method must be an array or implement the Traversable interface

/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:652
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:218
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-mvc/src/Application.php:263
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-test/src/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:230
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-test/src/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:255
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-test/src/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:344
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/module/Company/test/Controller/ManageControllerTest.php:29

Caused by
Laminas\ModuleManager\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Parameter to Laminas\ModuleManager\ModuleManager's Laminas\ModuleManager\ModuleManager::setModules method must be an array or implement the Traversable interface

/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php:262
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php:68
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-mvc/src/Service/ModuleManagerFactory.php:82
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:645
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:218
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-mvc/src/Application.php:263
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-test/src/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:230
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-test/src/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:255
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/vendor/laminas/laminas-test/src/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:344
/var/lxp/sites/cammslearning/production/application/module/Company/test/Controller/ManageControllerTest.php:29

This is the sample unit test I wrote
<?php
namespace CompanyTest\Controller;

use Company\Controller\ManageController;
use Laminas\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Laminas\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class ManageControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase {
    protected $traceError = true;

    protected function setUp(): void {
        $configOverrides = [];

        $configs = [
            include __DIR__ . '/../../../../config/application.config.global.php',
            include __DIR__ . '/../../../../config/autoload/testing.global.php',
        ];

        $mergedConfig = ArrayUtils::merge(
            $configs,
            $configOverrides
        );
        $this->setApplicationConfig($mergedConfig);

        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testDirectoryAction () {
        $this->dispatch('/company/directory');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
        $this->assertModuleName('Company');
        $this->assertControllerName(ManageController::class);
        $this->assertControllerClass('ManageController');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('company/directory');
    }
}

I also added autoload entry in the composer.json as well.
   "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ApplicationTest\\": "module/Application/Test/",
            "CompanyTest\\": "module/Company/test/"
        }
    },    

How do I get this running? what are the possible causes for this?
The other relevant files.
phpunit.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php" >
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Laminas MVC Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./module/Application/Test</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Login">
            <directory>./module/Learner/Authentication/test</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Company">
            <directory>./module/Company/test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>

Folder structure
.
└── application/
    ├── config/
    │   ├── application.config.global.php
    │   └── autoload/
    │       └── testing.global.php
    ├── module/
    │   └── Company/
    │       ├── Controller/
    │       │   └── ManageController.php
    │       └── test/
    │           └── Controller/
    │               └── ManageControllerTest.php
    ├── composer.json
    └── phpunit.xml


Your problem is simple. You're configuring incorrectly. You've declared the configured array incorrectly. Replace your setup code with below and it will help. You could have compared your result with the provided example in the Laminas MVC.
protected function setUp(): void {
        $configOverrides = include __DIR__ . '/../../../../config/autoload/testing.global.php';

        $configs = include __DIR__ . '/../../../../config/application.config.global.php';

        $mergedConfig = ArrayUtils::merge(
            $configs,
            $configOverrides
        );
        $this->setApplicationConfig($mergedConfig);

        parent::setUp();
    }

Please never put any testing files in the autoload directory or even in any module config directory. Keep it in your test directory under config. Because your test config will some how effect the result in the web.
